# Splitting a string and capitalizing letters based on cases

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have some column names with starting coding convention that I would like to transform, see example:

```
   Original        Target     
 ------------- -------------- 
  partID        Part ID       
  completedBy   Completed By
```

I have a function in VBA that splits the original string by capital letters:

```
Function SplitCaps(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
    SplitCaps = .Replace(strIn, "$1 $2")
End With
End Function
```

I wrap this function within PROPER, for example, PROPER(SplitCaps(A3)) produces the desired result for the third row but leaves the "D" in ID uncapitalized.

```
   Original        Actual    
 ------------- -------------- 
  partID        Part Id       
  completedBy   Completed By
```

Can anyone think of a solution to add cases to this function?

Comment: Well what's the rule, is ID the only exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split the word and loop the results and test whether it is all caps before using Proper.  then join them back:

```
Sub kjl()
Dim str As String
str = "partID"

Dim strArr() As String
strArr = Split(SplitCaps(str), " ")

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(strArr)
    If UCase(strArr(i)) <> strArr(i) Then
        strArr(i) = Application.Proper(strArr(i))
    End If
Next i

str = Join(strArr, " ")

Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

---

If you want a formula to do what you are asking then:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(EXACT(UPPER(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SplitCaps(A1)," ",REPT(" ",999)),{1,999},999))),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SplitCaps(A1)," ",REPT(" ",999)),{1,999},999))),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SplitCaps(A1)," ",REPT(" ",999)),{1,999},999)),PROPER(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SplitCaps(A1)," ",REPT(" ",999)),{1,999},999)))))
```

Entered as an array formula by confirming with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

Or use the code above as a Function:

```
Function propSplitCaps(str As String)

Dim strArr() As String
strArr = Split(SplitCaps(str), " ")

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(strArr)
    If UCase(strArr(i)) <> strArr(i) Then
        strArr(i) = Application.Proper(strArr(i))
    End If
Next i

propSplitCaps = Join(strArr, " ")
End Function
```

and call it `=propSplitCaps(A1)`

Comment: Brilliant formula. The function would have to wrap around OP's existing function I think as the string doesn't have any spaces?

Comment: @SJR yes it does, `strArr = Split(SplitCaps(str), " ")` calls the existing function.

Comment: Bah, sorry missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `Proper` function, just capitalize the first letter of each word after you have split the string on the transition.

```
Option Explicit
Function Cap(s As String) As String
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match
    Const sPatSplit = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
    Const sPatFirstLtr As String = "\b(\w)"
    Const sSplit As String = "$1 $2"
Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPatSplit
    .IgnoreCase = False
    If .Test(s) = True Then
        s = .Replace(s, sSplit)

        .Pattern = sPatFirstLtr
        Set MC = .Execute(s)
        For Each M In MC
            s = WorksheetFunction.Replace(s, M.FirstIndex + 1, 1, UCase(M))
        Next M
    End If
End With

Cap = s
End Function
```

[image]